# Why message.guild.me.permissions.has("X") returning me true

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, client

whatever i am writing inside `message.guild.me.permissions.has` it returns me true
Why ?

for example :

```
message.guild.me.permissions.has("X")  //  true ??
```

i am using **Discord.js v13**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`<Permissions>.has`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=has) can takes two parameters, `permission` and `checkAdmin` to true by default to override permissions if the user is administrator.

If you want to check if the user has a permission even if he is administrator you can pass it to false:

```
message.guild.me.permissions.has('X', false) // false
```